# Person tester application with inheritance and abstract classes

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I apologize in advance if there is more posts about this, I have looked through the postings that appeared relevant but could not find a solution.  I working on a project called a Person Tester in which;

1. the user is prompted to chose between creating a customer (c) or an employee (e).
2. next, the user is prompted to enter first, last name, e-mail adress and either customer number (if customer is selected), or social security  number (if employee is selected).
3. once the correct data has been gathered, the information is suposed to be printed to the console in this format:

   ```
       name: first last
       email: jondoe@fakemail.com
       social security number: XXXXXXXXXXX (if employee)
       customer number: XXXXXX  (if customer)
   ```
4. this program deals with inheritance and an abstract person class which is extended by an employee class and a customer class.  another stipulation states that the person class should contain an abstract method named getDisplayText that returns a string.

this is where my problem lies, this is my first time working with abstract classes.

MY QUESTION is why cant I simply print the toString method in my perosn class to display all the user data that was entered which brings me to my next issue, the program needs to have an additional component which is (and I quote from my assignment) : **To print the data for an object to the console, this application should use a static method named print that accepts a Person object.**

im not sure how to implement this since it was never discussed in class.  I have tried to simply code the following : System.out.print(aPerson.toString)  but all i get is blank value of Name:   and Social Security number:  . Im going nuts i have been working on this for several hours and re-read the relevant text at least 4 times.  this is my last resort.  please guide me in the right direction i dont mind working long hours to do this right.

I have written the majority of the application and am now just stuck on how to print the data to the console.  any and all suggestions are appreciated, this is my code:

```
public class CH08PR82App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Welcome to the Person Tester Application");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Person aPerson;
        aPerson = new Person();

        if (aPerson != null) {
            System.out.println(aPerson.toString());
        }

        String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

            //prompt user to enter customer or employee
            System.out.print("Create customer or employee (c/e): ");
            String userType = sc.nextLine();

            if (userType.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                String firstName = Validator.getStringInput(sc, "Enter first name: ");
                String lastName = Validator.getStringInput(sc, "Enter last name: ");
                String email = Validator.getStringInput(sc, "Enter email address: ");
                String custNumber = Validator.getStringInput(sc, "Customer number: ");
                //System.out.println(custNumber);
            } else if (userType.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
                String firstName = Validator.getStringInput(sc, "Enter first name: ");
                String lastName = Validator.getStringInput(sc, "Enter last name: ");
                String email = Validator.getStringInput(sc, "Enter email address: ");
                int empSoc = Validator.getInt(sc, "Social security number: ");
            }
            choice = Validator.getStringContinue(sc, "Continue? (y/n): ");
        }
    }
}

abstract class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String eMail;

    public Person() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        eMail = "";
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String geteMail() {
        return eMail;
    }

    public void seteMail(String eMail) {
        this.eMail = eMail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + this.firstName + this.lastName + "\n" + "E-mail: "
                + this.eMail;
    }

    abstract String getDisplayText();
}

abstract class Customer extends Person {

    private String customerNumber;

    public Customer() {
        super.toString();
        customerNumber = "";
    }

    public void setcustomerNumber(String customerNumber) {
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }

    public String getcustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "Social Security number: " + customerNumber
                + "\n";
    }
}

abstract class Employee extends Person {

    private String socNumber;

    public Employee() {
        super.toString();
        socNumber = "";
    }

    public void setsocNumber(String socNumber) {
        this.socNumber = socNumber;
    }

    public String getsocNumber() {
        return socNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "Social Security number:      " + socNumber
                + "\n";
    }
}

class Validator {
    public static String getStringContinue(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        String s = "";
        while (isValid == false) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNext("y")) {
                s = sc.nextLine(); // read entire line
                isValid = true;
            } else if (sc.hasNext("n")) {
                s = sc.nextLine();
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                s = sc.nextLine();
                isValid = false;
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid string value. Try again.");
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static String getStringInput(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        String s = "";
        while (isValid == false) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNext()) {
                s = sc.nextLine(); // read entire line
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid string value. Try again.");
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                i = sc.nextInt();
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer value. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine(); // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt, int min, int max) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            i = getInt(sc, prompt);
            if (i <= min) {
                System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater than " + min
                        + ".");
            } else if (i >= max) {
                System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than " + max
                        + ".");
            } else {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        double d = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                d = sc.nextDouble();
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid decimal value. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine(); // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return d;
    }

    public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt, double min,
            double max) {
        double d = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
            if (d <= min) {
                System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater than " + min
                        + ".");
            } else if (d >= max) {
                System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than " + max
                        + ".");
            } else {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the print method first:

```
public static void print(Person person) {
    System.out.println(person.toString());
}
```

Now you need an abstract method in your Person class:

```
public abstract String getDisplayText(Person person);
```

Which  you will override in your Employee and Customer classes:

```
// Employee
@Override
public String getDisplayText(Person person) {
    return ((Employee)person).toString();
}
```

and:

```
// Customer
@Override
public String getDisplayText(Person person) {
    return ((Customer)person).toString();
}
```

They wanted you to make the method abstract because each implementation is different - Customer has a customer ID, Employee has a Soc Number.

Now lets explain static and abstract methods: The difference between a static and abstract method is that an **abstract** method is just a header - implementation lies on children classes. Whereas a **static** method means that you can call it without creating an object in the first place.

Usage of this specific static method is very simple. Lets say you have:

```
Person john = new Customer();
... // Fill john with data
Person.print(john);
```

It also looks to me like you are a bit confused about all this abstract and static stuff. An abstract class is a class which can't create objects. In your example, you have an abstract class Person. The class is abstract because you either need a customer or an employee (both of which are people, hence the inheritance from Person class), but you don't want to store info about a person who is none of these. And that is also the reason why you can't do:

```
Person john = new Person(); // Build error
```

but you can (and should) do:

```
Person john = new Employee(); // Will compile and run
```

Comment: i do need to make my person class abstract, in my assignment description it says "create an abstract person class, and i did but then netbeans isnt happy about that and i cant declare my person class in the main method.  im also supposed to use an abstract method in the person class called getDisplayText(), so im not sure how to go about that since weve never done it in class.  appreciate any additional help.

Comment: I edited my whole answer. Read through it and let me know if you have more questions. :)

Comment: im kind of understanding what your saying, netbeans wnats me to make all my classes abstract, also do i need an override statement in my person class? and is my toString() method ok? (in my person class)

Comment: im sorry, one more question, when i go to initialize my person object in my main method, netbeans says, "person is abstract cannot be instantiated

Comment: i implemented everything, i dont have any red text but i simply cannot get the data to print out.  i implemented Person c = new Customer() and System.out.print(c.toString); but all i get is blank name:   blank email: blank customer number: blank